# Displaying an error message in the output xml if date comparison test expression is satisfied in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have to display an error message in the output xml whenever the revision date is greater than the publish date. I have to compare each and every revision date with the corresponding publish date for a book. There can be multiple "revision dates" in the input xml but there will be only one publish date for a book.

While running the XSLT code, the test expression in which I am performing date comparison is becoming false due to which the error message is not getting displayed in the output xml.

Below is the input XML:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <publish_date>2020-10-01</publish_date>
      <revision_date>2019-09-02</revision_date>
      <revision_date>2021-12-02</revision_date>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>John, Doe</author>
      <title>XPath Developer's Guide</title>
      <publish_date>2020-12-01</publish_date>
      <revision_date>2018-11-02</revision_date>
      <revision_date>2022-12-02</revision_date>
      <revision_date>2023-12-02</revision_date>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Below is the XSLT code snippet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/catalog/book">
    <xsl:for-each select="revision_date">
        <xsl:if test="xs:date(revision_date) &gt; xs:date(publish_date)">
            <Error><xsl:text>Revision date should be lesser than publish date.</xsl:text></Error>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Do any of the proposed solutions work for you?

Comment: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) the answer  that's helped you the most.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
<xsl:template match="revision_date[xs:date(.) gt xs:date(../publish_date)]">
  <Error>Revision date should be lesser than publish date.</Error>
</xsl:template>
```

No `<xsl:for-each>` now, just `<xsl:apply-templates select="revision_date"/>`

---

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="revision_date[xs:date(.) gt xs:date(../publish_date)]">
    <Error>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Revision date ', .,
                                 ' should be lesser than publish date ',
                                 ../publish_date)"/>
    </Error>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <publish_date>2020-10-01</publish_date>
      <revision_date>2019-09-02</revision_date>
      <revision_date>2021-12-02</revision_date>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>John, Doe</author>
      <title>XPath Developer's Guide</title>
      <publish_date>2020-12-01</publish_date>
      <revision_date>2018-11-02</revision_date>
      <revision_date>2022-12-02</revision_date>
      <revision_date>2023-12-02</revision_date>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <publish_date>2020-10-01</publish_date>
      <revision_date>2019-09-02</revision_date>
      <Error>Revision date 2021-12-02 should be lesser than publish date 2020-10-01</Error>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>John, Doe</author>
      <title>XPath Developer's Guide</title>
      <publish_date>2020-12-01</publish_date>
      <revision_date>2018-11-02</revision_date>
      <Error>Revision date 2022-12-02 should be lesser than publish date 2020-12-01</Error>
      <Error>Revision date 2023-12-02 should be lesser than publish date 2020-12-01</Error>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the inner `for-each` I think you want

```
 <xsl:if test="xs:date(.) &gt; xs:date(../publish_date)">
```